# Add parameterised hyperlink to SSRS report list

Tags: ssrs

We have a single SSRS report with a lot of parameters. End-users would like to have a single-click hyperlink that runs the SSRS report with the parameters pre-selected - that appears to be possible ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver16)).

Our problem now is that our users are accustomed to going to the SSRS Report portal and searching for the report they want to run (e.g. https://ssrs-server.domain.local/reports/browse).

How do I add a hyperlink to the list of "reports" that will launch the parameterized URL that launches our report with the preselected parameters? e.g. https://ssrs-server.domain.local/reports/report/path/to/ssrs-report?Parameter=1.

This report is used by multiple departments and can be used for different use cases depending on the parameters selected. My goal is to have a list of hyperlinks that runs the same report, each link specifying the parameters via the URL.

Comment: Could you not set the default parameter values of the report itself, so when they open it, it automatically runs?

Comment: Hi @J.D. - Multiple departments use this same report. The idea is to have multiple hyperlinks to the report with different default values.

Comment: You could deploy multiple copies of the report each instance with separate parameter values configured as the defaults.

Comment: @J.D. For version-control and management reasons I was hoping to avoid doing that. Any other suggestions? Anyone else?

Comment: You wouldn't need separate copies of the report `rdl` file. You would just change the path of deployment for each version (which you can automate a multitude of ways). You *may* need a separate folder on the SSRS server for each version to deploy to. But you can then create a shortcut (with something called a Linked Report) to each of them in the same main folder, if you wanted them all shown in the same place. From a version control / management perspective, you'd still only have 1 report to manage. This would basically emulate what you're trying to do. 

Comment: I certainly understand and appreciate your response. It doesn't, however, answer the question I asked. Automation that would duplicate the/upload multiple copies of the `rdl` file to SSRS (presumably under different file names) is more of a workaround rather than an answer on whether SSRS supports adding hyperlinks to the SSRS report browser. Or, if uploading/maintaining multiple copies of an `rdl` file is the only option available.

Comment: "*Automation that would duplicate...multiple copies of the rdl*" - You seem to not fully understand what I'm saying though. You don't need to actually duplicate the rdl, you would just be deploying the same one to SSRS multipe times. The only thing that changes is the `TargetReportFolder` property on the Report Project Properties (a single string). You can easily manage that with a separate Stash (if you're using source control in Visual Studio) to switch between deployments, or separate build configurations, etc. From the SSRS server it would look the same as hyperlink objects would look.

Comment: Also, using the technique I mentioned, the report would have the same file name and report name, because it's the same rdl, not a copy. Of course you could rename the report name for each deployed instance on the server if you wanted, but by default the names would be the same. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to achieve directly creating hyperlinks in SSRS without hacking together some kind of hardcoded SSRS template that lives directly on the server and would need to be manually maintained and deployed. But even then, not sure how possible it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all of that, a spark clicked in my brain, and I remembered I was overcomplicating it. You can simply use [Linked Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/create-a-linked-report?view=sql-server-ver16) in SSRS to completely create the "links" with the different parameters you're looking for.

Linked Reports are similar to creating a customizable shortcut to the original report in SSRS. The parameters of them can be configured differently than the source report. The nice thing though is they inherit the same report design and data sources as the original source report. So any changes to the report only needs to be deployed once, and all Linked Reports will have the updates automatically.

Some info from the previous linked docs:

> A linked report is a report server item that provides an access point to an existing report. Conceptually, it is similar to a program shortcut that you use to run a program or open a file.
>
> A linked report is derived from an existing report and retains the original's report definition. A linked report always inherits report layout and data source properties of the original report. All other properties and settings can be different from those of the original report, including security, parameters, location, subscriptions, and schedules.

Sorry, I was having a total mind fart until I remember this **is** essentially how to emulate hyperlinks in the SSRS repository.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you, J.D.

Comment: @user1913559 Np! Sorry for the brain fart lol.